# Installing Snipe-IT on Azure Web Apps

Tags: php, composer-php, azure-web-app-service

Has anyone here been able to install Snipe-IT (Open source asset management: https://snipe-it.readme.io/docs) on Azure Web Apps?

I know it is possible to install it on an Azure VM, since I've done that, but I would prefer it to be on a Web App so we keep everything simple and slightly more secure.

I have been able to download it from GitHub, and it then says that the document root is incorrect (It has to be \wwwroot\public instead of \wwwroot). So, I go ahead and change the document root to the public, but then the page returns a 500 error. I see that I need to install Composer, so I install the extension for that, but nothing changes. I know the document root works correctly because I am able to place a test file in the public directory and it works fine. It is just the actual Snipe-IT install that gets screwed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it:

1. Run the command `composer install` under \wwwroot folder to install dependencies.
2. Change the document root by setting the virtual application path for the web app.

   [image]
3. Edit the Snipe-IT configuration file (`.env` file) to configure the database credentials, app key and so on.
4. Restart the app service.

Finally, It worked for me.

[image]